# referencing one aspx.cs class in another aspx.cs class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

Does anyone know how to reuse the code from one aspx.cs class in another aspx page?

Comment: Inheritance is not an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see here [How many classes can you inherit from in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600881/how-many-classes-can-you-inherit-from-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you're ultimately doing, but one option would be to build a re-usable class in your App_Code folder and use it across your entire site.

Comment: I suggest that if you don't know how to reference classes, that you should go check out http://www.asp.net/get-started

Comment: @ChaseFlorell that so unhelpful. either help with another or say nothing, but linking to a page that says get started and has nothing to do with question, is really uncalled for.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should put your reusable methods in a seperate class in a seperate cs file.

But what you are asking for can also be easily done, here is an example:

**Page1.aspx.cs**

```
 public partial class MyPage1: System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        public static void MyTestFunction()
        {
            //Code Here           

        }

        public void MyTestFunction2()
        {
            //Code Here
        }
}
```

**Page2.aspx.cs**

```
    public partial class MyPage2: System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           MyPage1.MyTestFunction();  // static function call

           //or

           MyPage1 page1 = new MyPage1();
           page1.MyTestFunction2();           


        }

      }
```

Comment: If I make a separate cs file, how would I reference the methods/classes in that class?

Comment: Your reference other classes by declaring a new object in your page.

You probably need to grab hold of a c# book and start reading up. The questions you are asking are very basic, if you spend a day or two reading the book it will save you a lot of time in the long run.

I recommend reading C# 4.0 in a nutshell by Joseph Albahari and Ben Albahari 

or

Programming C# 4.0 by Ian Griffiths, Matthew Adams, and Jesse Liberty.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options for reuse in ASP.NET:

- Master pages
- user controls
- composite controls
- create a custom class which inherits from the Page class and have your pages inherit from that custom class
- Create a *helper* class which has reusable methods which you can use in your different webforms

Answer (score 0):

Reusing code in multiple pages should be done in a separate class as mentioned or by using another mechanism such as master pages, etc.  Trying to call code from multiple aspx pages without using backend classes is risky going forward with upgrades as it makes your app more brittle and harder to maintain over time.  frontend pages such as ASPX pages should contain their own independent codebehind only.  They should not reference another ASPX page.  A better model is to set up an object model prior to the GUI layer, then call into the object model from various pages.  That way, the page code is responsible only for it's own local page elements and any business logic needed across pages is housed elsewhere.  Again, if you need UI logic to be shared, use something like old-style include files, master pages, or user controls which can be very useful at sharing as well as separating out the concerns of each piece (that separation of concerns principle is very important and when done right can help your app remain clean and easy to upgrade later!)

Comment: How exactly could I go about creating classes then sharing them against various backend pages?

Comment: The namespaces in the helper classes and the aspx pages should be the same.  If not then you will need to add using statements at the top of your aspx page codebehind.  Then simply use your classes.  The helper classes should represent objects such as a Report, User, etc.  What type of functionality were you wanting to share between pages?