# Interface name expected - but I don't understand how to implement it

Tags: c#, interface

I have  the following class:

```
public abstract class CommonEvents : DisposableObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Internal method for storing error messages to our event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="showException"></param>
    /// <param name="exception"></param>
    public void OnError(string message, OnErrorEventsArgs.ShowExceptionLevel showException, Exception exception)
    {
        if (_onErrorEvent == null) return;

        var e = new OnErrorEventsArgs(message, showException, exception);

        _onErrorEvent(this, e);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Internal event handler allowing for logging of events within the class
    /// </summary>
    private EventHandler<OnErrorEventsArgs> _onErrorEvent;

    /// <summary>
    /// Public event handler allowing for accessibility outside of the class
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<OnErrorEventsArgs> OnErrorEvent
    {
        add { _onErrorEvent += value; }
        remove { _onErrorEvent += value; }
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to inherit it in one of my projects, however I'm already inheriting another class there, the code is below:

```
public class ItemDal : Common.Dal.BaseDal, CommonEvents
{
```

The error that I'm receiving is

> 'CommonEvents': Interface Name expected

When I researched this, I tried to build an interface - but then came up short as I don't understand enough to accomplish this. Can you please help me to understand this or point me in the direction of a good article to help me to do so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> And I'm trying to inherit it in one of my projects, however I'm already inheriting another class there

That's compiler's way of telling you that C# does not support multiple inheritance. If you put a class on the list of bases, the rest of the names must refer to interfaces.

You can inherit two classes only if one of them inherits the other, directly or indirectly; this way you inherit the most derived class, along with the other class that happens to be its base.

A common solution in C# is extracting an interface from one of the classes, embedding the instance of an implementation, and forward interface calls to the implementation included in your class through composition.

In your case it would look like this:

```
interface ICommonEvents {
    void OnError(string message, OnErrorEventsArgs.ShowExceptionLevel showException, Exception exception);
    event EventHandler<OnErrorEventsArgs> OnErrorEvent {add;remove;}
}
// Keep the implementation the same
public class CommonEvents : DisposanbleObject, ICommonEvents {
    ...
}
// Here is your derived class:
public class ItemDal : Common.Dal.BaseDal, ICommonEvents {
    private readonly CommonEvents ce = ... // Initialize your common events
    void OnError(string message, OnErrorEventsArgs.ShowExceptionLevel showException, Exception exception) {
        ce.OnError(message, showException, exception);
    }
    event EventHandler<OnErrorEventsArgs> OnErrorEvent {
        add {ce.OnErrorEvent += value;}
        remove {ce.OnErrorEvent -= value;}
    }
}
```

Comment: That's... less than ideal :| Shame.

Comment: @ElvisLikeBear That's not too hard to overcome, though - take a look at the edit.

Answer (score 3):

In C#, a `class` can only inherit one other `class` (though that class may inherit from another and so on).

Anything that follows that one `class` after the `:` must be an interface, so the compiler is expecting `CommonEvents` to be an `interface`, but it is not.

There are 2 approaches readily at hand here:

1. Have `Common.Dal.BaseDal` inherit `CommonEvents` (so `ItemDal` will inherit `CommonEvents` "through" `Common.Dal.BaseDal`.
2. Use one of your classes inside `ItemDal`. So `ItemDal` might expose members similar to the method, but all it does it call into the component, which contains all the logic. This is known as composition.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot inherit from multiple classes, you can inherit from classes and interfaces though

[How many classes can you inherit from in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600881/how-many-classes-can-you-inherit-from-in-c)

An Interface is basically a contract. You will need a concrete class to implement the contract.

You should either chain your inheritance e.g. B: A , C: B, or create an interface for CommonEvents like so:

```
 public interface ICommonEvents
{
    void BroadcastMessage(string text);
}

public class CommonEvents : ICommonEvents
{
    public void BroadcastMessage(string text)
    {

    }
}
```

And now you can implement the interface and take the concrete class CommonEvents as a dependency and delegate your methods to it

```
public class ItemDal : Common.Dal.BaseDal, ICommonEvents
{
    private readonly CommonEvents _commonEvents;

    public ItemDal(CommonEvents commonEvents)
    {
        _commonEvents = commonEvents;
    }

    #region Implementation of ICommonEvents

    void ICommonEvents.BroadcastMessage(string text)
    {
        _commonEvents.BroadcastMessage(text);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Before doing this I would urge you to consider your design if you REALLY need to do that though, as it probably violates the single responsibility principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Your DAL class should not be doing error handling

Answer (score 2):

CommonEvents is not an interface, it is an abstract class. An abstract class must be inherited while an interface is what the compiler was expecting. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scsyfw1d%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is a write-up on the difference. Can you change the abstract class into an interface and just put the code in a parent class? Like this

```
public interface class ICommonEvents 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Internal method for storing error messages to our event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="showException"></param>
    /// <param name="exception"></param>
    public void OnError(string message, OnErrorEventsArgs.ShowExceptionLevel showException, Exception exception);

    /// <summary>
    /// Internal event handler allowing for logging of events within the class
    /// </summary>
    private EventHandler<OnErrorEventsArgs> _onErrorEvent;

    /// <summary>
    /// Public event handler allowing for accessibility outside of the class
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<OnErrorEventsArgs> OnErrorEvent;
}

public class CommonEvents : DisposableObject, ICommonEvents
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Internal method for storing error messages to our event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="showException"></param>
    /// <param name="exception"></param>
    public void OnError(string message, OnErrorEventsArgs.ShowExceptionLevel showException, Exception exception)
    {
        if (_onErrorEvent == null) return;

        var e = new OnErrorEventsArgs(message, showException, exception);

        _onErrorEvent(this, e);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Internal event handler allowing for logging of events within the class
    /// </summary>
    private EventHandler<OnErrorEventsArgs> _onErrorEvent;

    /// <summary>
    /// Public event handler allowing for accessibility outside of the class
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<OnErrorEventsArgs> OnErrorEvent
    {
        add { _onErrorEvent += value; }
        remove { _onErrorEvent += value; }
    }
}

public class ItemDal : CommonEvents
{ ...
```